# Memory Leak when using __hook and __unhook with multiple inheried mfc classes

Tags: c++, events, mfc, hook, multiple-inheritance

In my MFC Dialog Class I use `__hook` and `__unhook` to register a handler to a event of one of my objects.

The Dialog Class:

```
// Header 
class CMyDlg : public CDialogEx, public CEffectController
{
public:
   CMyDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
   enum { IDD = IDD_MY_DIALOG };
protected:
   CEffect m_effect;
   virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
   afx_msg void OnDestroy();

private:
   void OnEffectReady();
   . . .
};

// CPP
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog
{
   CDialogEx::OnInitDialg();
   __hook(&Effect::effectReady, &m_effect, &CMyDlg::OnEffectReady);
   return TRUE;
}

void CMyDlg::OnDestroy
{
   __unhook(&Effect::effectReady, &m_effect, &CMyDlg::OnEffectReady);
   CDialogEx::OnDestroy();
}
```

The Parent Class:

```
class CEffectController
{
public:
   CEffectController();
   virtual ~CEffectController();
};
```

The Object Class:

```
class CEffect
{
public:
   CEffect();
   ~CEffect();

   __event void effectReady();
};
```

The problem is that whenever I either inherit from `CEffectController` **OR** use `__hook` and `__unhook` I get the following output of my debugger:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{352} normal block at 0x013E35E0, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <p               > 70 A6 C2 00 00 00 00 00 10 F7 0F 01 CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

Either **not** inhering from `CEffectController` **OR not** using `__hook` or `__unhook` fixes this problem.

I guess the use of function pointers in `__hook` cause a problem that some part of my class is not being unhooked by `__unhook` again.
Has anyone faced such a problem yet, or knows a possible solution or workaround for this?

Note: All functions, constructors, destructors get called!

Comment: You should run your code under the Application Verifier tool.  That should help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Do you have some specific tool in mind? :)

Comment: Application Verifier is the name of the tool. You can get it as a Microsoft download.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the leak is in `CEffectController`. If the address of the leaked block `{352}` is constant between runs, use [_CrtSetBreakAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wth1ha5.aspx) to force a breakpoint when that memory is allocated then you can see what it is.

Comment: @Vinzenz you found any solution for this? I am facing same problem.

Comment: @bala Sadly not, I guess it's some very rare bug in the MFC api that was not tested with C++ events and hooks :/
I dropped the idea of using events in my case and used an Interface with event listener methods instead which I pass as pointer to the constructor of `CMyDlg`

Comment: @Vinzenz than you for the suggestion. :)